# php | Convert array to select box

Tags: php, arrays, select

I have an array and would like to convert that to the select box. You could find my solution below. But I have a problem with my lats option output html layout. Where is my problem and how can I solve this issue?

**My code:**

```
if (isset($product->options) && count($product->options)) {

            $option_name = '';   
            foreach ($product->options as $option) {        
                if (trim($option_name) != trim($option->name)) {
                    echo '<select class="width-100" name="product[option][name]['.$option->name.']">';
                }   
                echo '<option value="'.$option->value.'">'.$option->value.'</option>';

                if (trim($option_name) != trim($option->name)) {
                    echo '</select>';
                }

                $option_name = $option->name;       
            }
        }
```

My output looks like:

```
<select class="width-100" name="product[option][name][Color]">
   <option value="Black">Black</option>
</select>
<select class="width-100" name="product[option][name][Size]">
   <option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>
<option value="X">X</option>
```

**My array:**

```
 [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Color
                    [value] => Black
                    [price] => +50
                    [order] => 
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Size
                    [value] => XL
                    [price] => +10
                    [order] => 
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Size
                    [value] => X
                    [price] => +5
                    [order] => 
                )

        )
```

Comment: what problem do you have?

Comment: Why you don't user for loop instead of foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isset($product->options) && count($product->options)) {
    $arr = [];

    foreach ($product->options as $option) {
        $arr[$option->name][] = '<option value="'.$option->value.'">'.$option->value.'</option>';
    }

    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
        echo '<select class="width-100" name="product[option][name]['.$k.']">';
        echo join("\n", $v);
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
   if (isset($product->options) && count($product->options)) {

        $option_name = '';   
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($product->options as $option) {        
            if (trim($option_name) != trim($option->name)) {
                echo '<select class="width-100" name="'.$option->name.'">';
            }   
            echo '<option value="'.$option->value.'">'.$option->value.'</option>';

            if (trim($option_name) != trim($option->name)) {
                echo '</select>';
            }

            $option_name = $option->name;       
            $i++; 
        }
    }
```